# Winapi equivalent for fsutil queryfilenamebyid command

Tags: c++, file, winapi, fsutil

The [fsutil queryfilenamebyid](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc788058.aspx) displays a random link name for a specified file ID on an NTFS volume. I would like to do this programmatically using some winapi function(s) but I've failed to find any winapi equivalent via google searches.

Does anyone know if such a winapi function exists?

Answer (score 2):

Look at [`OpenFileById()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365432.aspx) and [`GetFileInformationByHandleEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364953.aspx).